# GLSL associating multiple uniform samplerBuffers

Tags: opengl, glsl

At the moment I'm not sure how my VBO and TBO associate with a specific uniform samplerBuffer in my shader, I have not linked them using the location or the vbo/tbo together. It seems to still work though, but now that I am using multiple samplerBuffers, how do I establish to link between a specific TBO and the uniform. Do I need to use glUniformX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For VBOs you don't use uniforms, but to deference them you use shader attributes instead.

Regarding Texture buffer objects (TBO) you can bind their uniform location in the shader,

```
layout (binding = 0) uniform sampler2D tex_object;
```

You can also get its location using glGetUniformLocation and then set the TBO uniform value using `glUniformi( location, tbo)`.

Inorder to tie VBO and TBO together use `glTexBuffer`

```
// Attach the VBO to TBO.
glGenTextures(1, &tbo);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, tbo);
glTexBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL_RGBA32F, vbo);
```

Comment: Yes, I was wondering how the uniform knows which TBO to use, so glUniformi using the TBO as the id makes sense to me now, thanks!

Comment: Actually, using TBO (for glUniform1i) seems to break it. Is it because I'm not doing something properly?

Comment: I usually use `layout (binding = 0)` you can also use glGetUniformLocation to make sure it's the correct location. glUniformi should work for samples, I am not sure what is wrong.